# Two router setup with public ip to allow port forwarding

Tags: router, portforwarding, virtual-server

In my country, our internet is accessed, in most homes, through the phone cables.

So you normally have a simple modem/router that accepts a dsl-cable.

Now, I have a project where I need to put an application online.

For this, I have bought a TP-Link TL-R407t+ and I have a Technicolor modem/router with wifi.

The setup now goes like this: phone outlet --> technicolor --> TP-Link.

This gives me wifi from the technicolor and the internet through the tp-link works through an ethernet too.

The TP-Link, I have set up for port forwarding. Yet, what remains is that the TP-Link has a private ip. I am lost in figuring out how I get it to use the public IP, so that once I write xx.xx.xx.xx:8080 or whatever into a browser, my app shows up.

So my question is, how do I setup my routers, or add stuff, to allow the port forwarding to work.

Comment: already configured some nat service? the best way will be through services like https://www.noip.com/

Comment: But is that necessary? Isn't there a way to use the original public ip given by the internet provider.

Comment: yes, so i asked if it had NAT configured, if not on your router you should have an option like Setup NAT or Setup NAT(1-1), in which you forward the request from your public IP to one of your internal IPs.

Comment: Aaah, now I understand, my bad. The only nat changes, I have made is on the tp-link where I port forwarded. That nat change, you mention, is that to be done on the technicolor?

Comment: if your tp-link is as a secondary router yes, which router is with DHCP. One question why the tp-link router?
technicolor has some limitation in connections??